# Kubernetes namespace terminates/disappears when all its pods are deleted

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes namespace terminates/disappears when all its pods are deleted.  I created a secret in that namespace, which is now gone.
Is that normal behavior?  It doesn't seem right.  Why should it disappear just because empty?

Comment: No. Namespace is top level entity. It shouldn't get deleted because of deletion of any resources inside it. Can you share the command how you have deleted the pods? Also, can you check if the Namespace has any owner reference?

Comment: Happening with me as well

Answer (score 1):

namespace is a logical grouping of resources for a specific application or services. resources can be deleted from a namespace. it doesn't automatically delete the namespace. You must be doing something different.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The only command I execute is ```kubectl delete -f loggly/loggly.yaml```
Soon after, the namespace is no longer listed.   I'm quite certain this is the only thing I do, so unless something in my yaml file suggests that the namespace should be deleted???

Comment: most likely the namespace deletion is also part of the loggly.yaml. check and confirm